# Can't fix this color glitch when joining objects

Tags: modeling, objects, color, object-mode

I have this problem with my modelling, I am in the middle of modelling and I am on a time limit. After modelling my hand as a separate object from the body I cannot join the hand and body without running into this color problem. Whenever I join the two objects the object that I select first turns a darker shade.
For example, if I select the hand first and then body second when I press join the hand will lose its modifiers (Which I actually don't mind, I want it to have the body's modifiers) and will turn a darker shade. Same vice versa. I've attached images to give an example.

I'm not sure what may have caused this or how to fix it. Is there way I can possibly fix this?

[image: Objects before merging.]

[image: Selecting hand first, body second, then merging.]

[image: Selecting body first, then hand, then merging.]

Comment: Modifiers will be preserved on the object which was selected last prior to joining. Grey color is likely due to unapplied negative scale on one of objects, before joining try to select it in Object mode, press Ctrl+A > Scale. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30667/object-is-darker-after-joining-it-with-another-object-just-like-it

Answer (score 2):

1. Apply the scale at both objects: in Object mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then `Scale`
2. join them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
3. if the issue persists: go to edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select all <kbd>A</kbd> and hit Normals `Recalculate` in the Shading/UV tab of the toolbox (Shortcut would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

[image: The toolbox] [image: Recalculate]